# Can I setup my application deployment with Azure Windows Virtual Desktop(Preview) without azure active directory?

Tags: azure, virtualization, vdi

I want to test my application deployment with Azure Windows Virtual Desktop(Preview), but we do not have azure active directory setup in my application azure deployment. As we are doing lift & shift of our existing on-premise deployment, we have created a domain controller and setup a windows active directory into it on an azure VM. 
In msdn documentation for WVD setup, I found multiple steps involved the Azure Active directory. Is it possible to create a WVD setup using the domain controller?

Comment: you also need Azure Active Directory:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/tenant-setup-azure-active-directory

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD extends on-premises Active Directory environments into the cloud, enabling users to use their primary organizational account to sign in not only to their domain-joined devices and company resources, but also to all the web and SaaS applications they need for their jobs.

And Important part of WVD Requirement is An Azure Active Directory and domain controller in sync with Azure Active Directory.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/overview#requirements